# I want to change the state of text on my Layout file when I go onto a new page - c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

new to C# so just need help with a question!

I'm currently designing a website using C# and a MVC framework. I currently have four pages. I want to be able to change the site title which I know is in the layout file to the name of the current web page displayed. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ViewBag. Use it in Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

</head>
```

and in your page set ViewBag.Title. For example Home.cshtml(your page) should containt:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";//this value you define in page and read it in Layout
}
```

Also you should have in _ViewStart.cshtml your layout defined. Fox example:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: That worked a treat! I thought it was going to be more complicated

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewBag object to update title in each view:

SomeView.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Some Title";
}
```

Layout.cshtml

```
<title>@(ViewBag.Title == null ? "Default title" : ViewBag.Title)</title>
```